# CPU(MCU) freezing mechanism due to control voltage dip

Tags: microcontroller, cpu

I used to develop CPU boards before.
I have been wondering why CPU is stop when there are noise on the DC control power line.

I thought about the mechanism.
when voltage is droped. Internal register and memory value can be changed.
And, program counter register will be wrong.
So, program will jump to wrong address.
And then, program will meet oxff or ox00.
These HEX means stop the CPU.

It is just my senario(throught)

Do you know The the mechanism of CPU(MCU) stop when the dc power has a big noise.

Comment: Can you indicate what specific microcontroller architecture? The meaning of uninitialized bits, common sequences like 00 or ff, as well as other error handling, depends on the exact architecture.

Comment: It might be latching due to overvoltage. If it's an undervoltage it is browning out.

Comment: I usually saw the problem with PIC, AVR(ATMEGA)

Comment: CPUs have a specification for minimum and maximum voltage for normal operation.  If your noise causes the voltage to move outside of that specification you could corrupt the state of processor or cause damage to it.  This is why attention is usually paid to providing a stable voltage to CPUs.

Comment: Its hard to know exactly what happens but what you describe is not unrealistic. Suffice to say voltage levels get violated and strange things happen.